# Unable to record transaction time in Loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I prepared LR TruClient script. There are 5 transactions in my script. When I execute script in browser it getting passed successfully. When I ran through Vugen it's getting passed but for one transaction I am not able getting response time. It is throwing me below error. What is the meaning of that error and how can I resolve it?

> Internal problem -205177: In TransactionsAdapter::HandleMessage, calling EndTransaction failed

Comment: Can you provide more details? Which version of LoadRunner are you using and whether it is the community edition? Do you have any failed steps in your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested, more details would help. If you are using Loadrunner 12.02 it is a known issue and here you can download the fix:

https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/LoadRunner-User-Discussions/Failed-to-end-transaction-error-in-Truclient-12-02/td-p/555735

Answer (score 0):

Usually these types of errors are caused because the StartTransaction name and the endTransaction name are not equal. Verify the spelling is 100% equal in the startTransaction statement and in the endTransaction statement and that will probably fix your issue.

startTranstaction ("TransactionName")
endTransaction ("TransactionName", "LR_AUTO"); --> This will work
endTransaction ("Transactionname", "LR_AUTO"); --> This wont work. "n" from Name is not capital as in startTransaction statement.